# Is it possible to set an e-mail placeholder using "mailto": in HTML?

Tags: html

Im setting a bug report option for my website using "mailto:" and wanted to set a placeholder for the subject of my email field that way the user doesn't have to delete it all when they type. Is this possible, or is subject the closest thing to?

Comment: href="mailto:chrishutchison.dev@gmail.com?Subject=Bug Report&placeholder=placeholder"

Comment: How user can change "placeholder" of this link ?

Comment: no user isn't supposed to change it i only made placeholder = placeholder for test purposes to see if any text would even work

Comment: Really, i don't know what you want to do exactly... Please provide a example on your post and clear explanation

Comment: i explained it well i thought? so basically how if i did href="mailto:chrishutchison.dev@gmail.com?Subject=Bug Report&body=email body " the body of email would be email body i want to do the same thing like that but instead of body text it be a placeholder so as soon as the user types in email body the text disappears

Comment: No, I don't think its possible to give a placeholder for mail subject using mailto.

Comment: unfortunate :/ thank you though @TheTom